# Does += really do in-place addition in python?

Tags: python, variables, memory, memory-management, in-place

I am trying to test the in-place addition claim of += in python, this is my code:

```
>>> a=1
>>> id(a)
4346593520
>>> a+=1
>>> id(a)
4346593552
```

As you can see, the addresses are different, but could it be due to the fact that `4346593552` holds the value `2` already?

Because, when I am assigning same values to two different variable, their addresses turn out to be the same. i.e.

```
>>> b=13
>>> c=13
>>> id(b)==id(c)
True
```

Please clarify if I am correct in my assumption, otherwise the in-place addition looks skeptical to me

Comment: int objects are immutable by design.

Answer (score -1):

+= Addition Assignment
Description
Adds a value and the variable and assigns the result to that variable.

Syntax
A += B

A
Any valid object.
B
Any valid object.
Return Value
According to coercion rules.

Remarks
Equivalent to A = A + B.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOslZ.png)